# No Correlation Plot in Pandas-Profiling Report

Tags: pandas, correlation, pandas-profiling

Running Pandas profiling report, and no correlation graph is being generated even when there are valid numeric variables with strong correlations. The following code generates a profile report in which the Correlation section is blank.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 3)), columns=list('XYZ'))

pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(df)
```

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Modified my question to include example.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this problem has been resolved in [pull request #159](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/pull/159) (corresponding to version 1.4.1 and upwards).

You can install the latest version via:

```
pip install -U pandas-profiling
```

If you want to stick to version 1.x (for Python 2 support), you can install this specific version via:

```
pip install pandas-profiling==1.4.1
```